# Android 8.0 and up: Monitor battery level changes while app is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

As the title says, I am looking for a way to monitor the level of the device battery even while the app is not running.
`context.registerReceiver()` worked out well, but sadly only with the app running.

Is there any way I did not think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is became restricted starting from Android 8+. Have a look at the documentation [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)

You might try `WorkManager` to periodically check for battery status

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to just subscribe to this like an event? If I would use WorkManager, what time period would you recommend so not to stress the device too much?